# What do 'en.' and 'more'n' mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context, dialects

The passage, from The Invisible Man by H.G.Wells, is following:

"'Tas sperits," said Mrs. Hall. "I know 'tas sperits. I've read in papers of **en.** Tables and chairs leaping and
dancing..."
"Take a drop more, Janny," said Hall. "'Twill steady ye."
"Lock him out," said Mrs. Hall. "Don't let him come in again. I half guessed—I might ha' known. With them goggling eyes and bandaged head, and never going to church of a Sunday. And all they bottles—**more'n** it's right for any one to have. He's put the sperits into the furniture.... My good old furniture! 'Twas in that very chair my poor dear mother used to sit when I was a little girl. To think it should rise up against me now!"

Comment: The first is a dialect form of 'them' and the second is a shortened form of 'more than'.

Comment: Both are archaic contractions. @mynamite Any references about *en* ( *'em* ) would be appreciated, it's interesting.

Comment: @Kris: *"more'n"* is not archaic; people use it in speech all the time. It's usually not contracted when written, but it wasn't in H.G. Wells's days, either.

Comment: @PeterShor Are we talking *more and* or *more than*?

Comment: @Araucaria: We're talking *more than*. I am fairly sure that this contraction is still used in speech reasonably often today. You can find it, for instance, in [song lyrics](http://www.oldielyrics.com/lyrics/peter_paul_and_mary/in_the_wind_album_liner_notes_by_bob_dylan.html).

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I can hear it in my head and it sounds ok, but I wasn't sure if that was just *more and* playing tricks on me ...

Comment: In America you'd mostly hear _more'n_ as part of a Southern accent.

Comment: @Kris Afraid I haven't got any references, my comment is based solely novels I've read, a vague familiarity with other attempts to write dialects, and Ockham's razor (what else could 'en' reasonably mean?). As to which particular dialect, I've no idea. Presumably I'd find out if I read the rest of the book, but how accurate is HG Wells's transcription? Maybe it's just a mish-mash of what he thought was a 'country' accent.

Comment: @Barmar I can definitely confirm as a Southerner for modern English.  I frequently use both *more'n* and *more'n'* in speech.

Comment: @Mynamite Or, did you by chance mean "The first is a dialect form of **'then'** ?"

Comment: @Kris No, because that wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both words suggest her dialect, in the same way as "ha'" in the sentence "I might ha' known". The first, "en", in used in the same way as the contraction "'em" might be for the word "them". Some English accents and dialects use this, especially those considered rural archetypes by speakers of Standard English/those with 'Home Counties'-type accents. Examples would be accents found in Dorset or Somerset; I can't be sure but I think old Sussex accents may also use it. I know I've read it in older texts (I think Hardy, possibly) but it isn't necessarily archaic; the use is phonetic spelling to evoke accent and often, by extension, social class.

"More'n" is a similar contraction and just means "more than".

Comment: BTW You still haven't said what "en" is a contraction for (okay, *used in the same way as the contraction "'em"* but for what?). I'm asking because there's some confusion over here.

Comment: @Kris: the word *"en"* is a short form of *"them"*. This was indeed said in the answer (although it was worded ambiguously): *"'en' is used ... for the word 'them'"*. This isn't standard; that's why the answer calls it ***dialect***.